# buiding android sdk

Tags: android

how to build sdk from source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [there](http://source.android.com/download).

> To build the Android source files, you will need to use Linux or Mac OS. Building under Windows is not currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

The command for building the sdk is `make sdk`.

Answer (score 1):

The steps to build the SDK are described in http://tools.android.com/build including the steps to build the Windows SDK (which is done under Linux.)